# Why do I get an error of "free(): invalid pointer"?

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, free, realloc

I am fairly new to C and I am using gcc compiler with -ansi.

I am trying to implement Strassen's algorithm for square matrix multiplication in C. As a warmup, I am just implementing a recursive algorithm first, which breaks each matrix into 4 submatrices (with the idea that I'll implement Strassen's algorithm later).

The program is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int** read_square_matrix(int size); /*returns dynamically allocated size x size matrix*/
int** square_matrix_multiply_helper(int** A,int** B, int row1, int col1, int row2, int col2, int size); /*recursively compute product. Assumes size is power of two*/
int** square_matrix_multiply(int** A,int** B, int size);/*expands dimension to a power of two if necessary and computes product*/
int main()
{
    int** A;
    int** B;
    int** C;
    int i,size;

    printf("Enter size: ");
    scanf("%d",&size);

    printf("Enter array A: ");
    A = read_square_matrix(size);

    printf("Enter array B: ");
    B = read_square_matrix(size);

    C = square_matrix_multiply(A,B,size);
    printf("Their product is:\n");
    print_square_matrix(C,size);
    for (i=0;i<size;++i)
    {
        free(A[i]);
        free(B[i]);
        free(C[i]);
    }
    free(A);
    free(B);
    free(C);

    return 0;
}
```

The code works fine for size=1,2,4. When I try two 3x3 matrices, say all 1, is where it fails. Specifically free(A[i]) fails on the first iteration with the error

```
free(): invalid pointer
```

Now by looking around, seems like this means that A[i] was not allocated by malloc. I don't see how this is possible. Here is the code for the matrix multiplication:

```
int** square_matrix_multiply(int** A, int** B, int size)
{
    int** C;
    int power,i,j;
    power = 1;
    while (power<size)
        power*=2;
    if (size<power)
    {
        A = realloc(A,power*sizeof(int*));
        B = realloc(B,power*sizeof(int*));
        for (i=0;i<size;++i)
        {
            A[i] = realloc(A[i],power*sizeof(int));
            B[i] = realloc(B[i],power*sizeof(int));
            for (j=size;j<power;++j)
            {
                A[i][j] = 0;
                B[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }
        for (i=size;i<power;++i)
        {
            A[i] = malloc(power*sizeof(int));
            B[i] = malloc(power*sizeof(int));
            for (j=0;j<power;++j)
            {
                A[i][j] = 0;
                B[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    C = square_matrix_multiply_helper(A,B,0,0,0,0,power);
    for (i=size;i<power;++i)
    {
        free(A[i]);
        free(B[i]);
        free(C[i]);
    }
    A = realloc(A,size*sizeof(int*));
    B = realloc(B,size*sizeof(int*));
    C = realloc(C,size*sizeof(int*));
    for (i=0;i<size;++i)
    {
        A[i] = realloc(A[i],size*sizeof(int));
        B[i] = realloc(B[i],size*sizeof(int));
        C[i] = realloc(C[i],size*sizeof(int));
    }
    return C;
}
```

I've been looking at this for hours, and I cannot figure out what's wrong. Can someone help me please? Thank you!
EDIT: implementation of read_square_matrix:

```
int** read_square_matrix(int size)
{
    int** C;
    int i,j;
    C = malloc(size*sizeof(int*));
    for (i=0;i<size;++i)
    {
        C[i] = malloc(size*sizeof(int));
        for (j=0;j<size;++j)
            scanf("%d",&C[i][j]);
    }
    return C;
}
```

Comment: None of the addresses from the `realloc` calls for `A` and `B` are retained when the `square_matrix_multiply` function exits. `A` in that function is *local* to the function. Any assignments to `A` inside the function are lost when the function returns. That is, the caller does not see the `realloc` memory.

Comment: Can you show the implementation of read_square_matrix?. Are you using malloc to build matrix?

Comment: @Sameer Yes. I'm adding it now.

Comment: @kaylum Surely then there is no issue. I temporarily expand A,B to add zero rows and columns then revert them to the original size. The original A,B are still allocated with malloc so I don't see why they cannot be freed.

Comment: [man relloc](https://linux.die.net/man/3/realloc): `if the area pointed to was moved, a free(ptr) is done`. That is, the original memory is freed by `realloc` so you are doing a double free.

Comment: @kaylum: Thanks. I didn't know that. So in effect you're saying that the rows of A,B are uninitialized after exit from square_matrix_multiply? Is there no way to fix this other than to create local copies of A,B?

Comment: Worse than uninitialised. They are pointing to the old memory blocks which are freed. That is, they are dangling pointers. I'll try to write up an answer with suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `square_matrix_multiply` function, you should pass the addresses of `int** A` & `int** B`.Change it to `int** square_matrix_multiply(int*** A, int*** B, int size)`, the `C = square_matrix_multiply(A,B,size)` should be `C = square_matrix_multiply(&A,&B,size)`, and change the implements of `square_matrix_multiply`.

Comment: It may help to clarify that the problem is that `square_matrix_multiply` invalidates the original values of `A` and `B` by passing them to `realloc`, but it doesn't return the new values to the caller.

Comment: In the `square_matrix_multiply`, 
using `*A = realloc(*A,power*sizeof(int*));
*B = realloc(*B,power*sizeof(int*));`